# Results not showing after search term entered from keyboard

Tags: python, python-2.7, add-on, xbmc, kodi

I am learning to develop an addon for Kodi and need to implement a search functionality. I found some resources online to get user input from keyboard and then calling an API with the search term to fetch results. The API is being requested fine but the results are not being shown through `ListItems`. Below is my code

```
_url = sys.argv[0]
_handle = int(sys.argv[1])

def get_url(**kwargs):
  return '{0}?{1}'.format(_url, urlencode(kwargs))

def display_main_menu():
    list_item = xbmcgui.ListItem(label="Search")
    url = get_url(action='search')
    xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(_handle, url, list_item)

def perform_search(search_term):
    link = "api_url_here" + search_term

    r = requests.get(link)

    resp = json.loads(r.text)

    for result in resp:
        list_item = xbmcgui.ListItem(label=result["name"])
        list_item.setArt({'thumb': result["img"], 'icon' : result["img"], 'fanart' : result["img"]})
        url = '' #blank url for testing
        is_folder = True
        xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(_handle, url, list_item, is_folder)

    xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(_handle)

def search():
  keyb = xbmc.Keyboard('',"Search for Videos", False)
  keyb.setDefault('')
  keyb.doModal()

  if (keyb.isConfirmed() and len(keyb.getText()) > 0):
    perform_search(keyb.getText())

def router(paramstring):
  params = dict(parse_qsl(paramstring))

  if params:
    if params['action'] == 'search':
        search()

    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid paramstring: {0}!'.format(paramstring))

  else:
    display_main_menu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  router(sys.argv[2][1:])
```

When I select `Search` and then type my word to search the keyboard is dismissed but nothing happens. The same menu is being displayed and new ListItems from the `perform_search` function are not being displayed. Also, there is no error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add some logging, the interesting part will be if you actually hit the for. So add some `xbmc.log('hit')` or even log your values.

If you want a full blown logging check this example https://github.com/xbmc/generator-kodi-addon/blob/master/generators/app/templates/resources/lib/kodilogging.py

Comment: I added logging statements after almost every step and all log statements were executed including the for. I also tried to print the retrieved search results i.e. `result["name"]` to the log and the results are being printed in the log but the results do not show as ListItems